# template design is bigger than bootstrap grid

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, photoshop

I have a psd template that i would like to convert to a responsive site using bootstrap.
The template width is 1920px and the bootstrap grid is a 1170px bootstrap grid with 12columns with 15px margins left and right.
But in the design some things like the logo in this example and a part of the menu stands out of the grid, how do i interpret this design then? Or is this wrong design? Am I correct if i think the design should be between the columns?
[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfCGZ.png) 
[image: template2]

Comment: You can use bootstrap with the `.container-fluid` class and have a full width design.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the menu and logo are included in the `<nav>` which comes before `<div class="container">`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Company 2017</p>
  </footer>
```

So the grid width is only referring to the width of the content in the container.

[image]